# How to set asp-items and asp-for in a loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Can anybody help me with the syntax (if this is doable) setting up asp-items parameter in a loop dynamically?
Basically, my ViewBag has items Q1, Q2, Q3. Each of these has a selectList for a dropdown.
I am looping though all the questions in Model.Questions, and for every one of these questions I need to get the select dropdown, which is stored in ViewBag. So it would be
ViewBag.Q1, then ViewBag.Q2 etc. I tried constructing a string "ViewBag.@questionId", but I get an error about type (string when it's expecting a list).

I hope you can help!

```
        @foreach (var question in Model.Questions) //For every question, generate question, and generate responses
        {
            <div class="form-row">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">@question.QuestionText</label>
                @if (question.QuestionResponse.Count() != 0) //If count ViewData[QID] != 0, generate select dropdown, otherwise, input.
                {                            
                    var questionId = "Q"+question.QuestionId.ToString();
                    
                    <select class="form-control col-md-4" asp-items="ViewBag.???"><option></option></select>
                    
                }

                else
                {
                    <input class="form-control col-md-4" />
                }
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change your code like below.

```
   var questionId = "Q" + question.QuestionId.ToString();

   <select class="form-control col-md-4" asp-items="(SelectList)ViewData[questionId]"><option></option></select>
```